# Beyond Compare - via command Line : Spaces in FilePath

Tags: command-line, beyondcompare

I am trying to run beyond compare via command line.

The command I am using is :

```
BCompare.exe @"My Config File.txt" "File 1.xml" "File 2.xml"
```

But this is not working because of spaces in the file Names.

Beyond Compare shows a "file not found" error (as it is looking only for the part of fileName before spaces)

If I compare files without any space in file name, it works.

Comment: Also, the configuration given in "My Config File.txt " are read correctly. The issue is with Spaces in filenames for files to be compared

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're running a script but haven't shown that, I suspect you aren't quoting the arguments there properly.  The quotes on the command line are going to be stripped as part of the command line processing, so if your script is:

```
file-report layout:side-by-side %1 %2 output-to:printer
```

It should actually be

```
file-report layout:side-by-side "%1" "%2" output-to:printer
```

Without the extra quotes the variables would be expanded like:

```
file-report layout:side-by-side File 1.xml File 2.xml output-to:printer
```

Comment: Thanks Zoe, This is exactly what I was missing